# View data web sql from old application in current browsers

Tags: angular, ubuntu, browser, web-sql

I have a relatively old application developed in Angular, the problem is that it works with Web SQL and, as you know, current browsers do not support it.

For my bad luck, I have to check certain parameters that are in the web sql of the application, how can I enable web sql in current browsers or look for a browser that allows me to read web sql in kubuntu 22.04?

I've tried using Wine and installed older versions of the browsers but I can't see the data.

I also looked for browsers that support web sql, but I can't get it to run on my kubuntu 22.04.

Any suggestion would be very helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone going through the same problem, the chromium 98 version worked for me for kubuntu 22.04
https://chromium.cypress.io/